# Android - how to send file via Bluetooth to a paired device in background

Tags: android, bluetooth

Now I'm trying to do some sync via Bluetooth between 2 devices.

My question is: is that possible that I can send file via Bluetooth to an already paired device?

So, I don't need to select Bluetooth for share option, and I don't need to select device as destiny.

If it's possible, that means I can run the sync between 2 devices via Bluetooth in the background.

Anyone please help.
Thanks!